# Trigger Jenkins build via curl with additional parameter

Tags: jenkins, curl

I'm trying to trigger the Jenkins build via `curl` command with additional parameter as described in the following image: [image]
I'm using `--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"text", "value":"develop:test"}]}'` but it doesn't work.

```
curl -X POST --user "${userName}:${password}" -H "Jenkins-Crumb:33c13aed5548ad43bf5e2eb276cf21af" "JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters" --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"text", "value":"develop:test"}]}'
```

JenKins still build with the default parameter instead: [image]
Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Well, what is the problem? You are not describing any issues

Comment: You need to look at the API documentation for correct formatting of the json  but besides that are you using a passowrd or API key?

Comment: You can use google chrome to inspect the page when doing something manually, then and look at the response. typically using an example I use to add devices to jenkins frontend, you'll require the api key. It should be something like. `curl -v -u '${userName}:${APIKEY}' -H 'Jenkins-Crumb:33c13aed5548ad43bf5e2eb276cf21af' -X POST -d 'json={"name":+"text",+"Value:value"+"Jenkins-Crumb":+"77e5db85d4773caecf2a6ffda96c4c3279e00619e62803a7a22cc5af6286e8f0"}' ...` obviously not everything is there, but it shows you how I fornat it. The API key is key though..

Comment: @Gerhard: Sorry, I've updated my question.